# Find objects from an IEnumerable List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I would like to find particular controls in `IEnumerable<Control>`.

Results contain a number of controls like `System.Web.UI.LiteralControls`, `...ContentPlaceHolders` etc.

How can I retrieve a list of Textboxes for example?

Answer (score 6):

You could try [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> textboxes = myEnumerable.OfType<TextBox>();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can achieve it quickly using LINQ:**

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> textboxes = myEnumerable.OfType<TextBox>();
```

**or "manualy":**

```
var textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

foreach(var ctrl in controls)
{
  if( ctrl is TextBox )
  {
     textBoxes.Add(ctrl);
  }
}
```